How to process data internally so that it becomes equivalent to what it would be when outputted to terminal
I have this string: "birthday_balloons.\u202egpj"
If I execute print("birthday_balloons.\u202egpj") it outputs
birthday_balloons.jpg

Note how the last three characters are reversed. I want to process the string "birthday_balloons.\u202egpj" in such a way that I get the string "birthday_balloons.jpg", with the order of the characters just like they were displayed.
I'm looking for a way to internally process a piece of data so that it becomes equivalent to what it would appear as when outputting it to the terminal without doing anything like literally capturing the output from terminal.

This question is similar to: Removing right-to-left mark and other unicode characters from input in Python. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@KirillIlichev, no that just removes those marks. They want to interpret those marks so they affect the order of characters in the string.

you could try parsing the unicode, something like unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', ) should work

After your edit: what do you mean with "internally"? Is there any other way that is not "internally"?

U+202E is RIGHT-TO-LEFT OVERRIDE (RLO), it marks the start of a bidirectional override forcing the following text to be rendered right-to-left regardless of the direction of the characters. It is closed by U+202C POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING (PDF).
Its presence in a filename would be indicative of malicious intent, in a terminal that supports bidirectional formatting, the string 'birthday_balloons.\u202egpj' would visually appear to be 'birthday_balloons.jpg', although most terminals do not have full bidi support. The override is more problematic within a web service or web page.
The final five characters of the string are 002E 202E 0067 0070 006A, i.e. . RLO g p j.
The simplest approach is to split the filename into components, test for an override, then clean components of the filename containing an override using a list comprehension:
import re

# Test for presence of an RLO character
def override_exists(text):
    return re.search(r'\u202e', text)

# Remove RLO and PDF characters and reverse string
def repair_string(text):
    return re.sub(r'[\u202c\u202e]', '', text)[::-1]

# Split file name and use list comprehension to test and repair string.
def clean_file_name(file_name):
    components = file_name.split('.')
    cleaned = [repair_string(comp) if override_exists(comp) else comp for comp in components]
    return ".".join(cleaned)

s = 'birthday_balloons.\u202egpj'
print(clean_file_name(s))
# birthday_balloons.jpg

Although, the repair mechanism is masking the problem and possibly creating a security vulnerability.
A better approach would be for the repair functionality to just be
def repair_string(text):
    return re.sub(r'[\u202c\u202e]', '', text)

so:
print(clean_file_name(s))
birthday_balloons.gpj

This will remove The RLO, and display the filename in a way that will show the file extension is not .jpg and is suspect. Alternatively, the override detection could raise or log and exception.
Update:
Given the comments below, I'll add to my answer. Python stores bidi text in logical order. For the string 'birthday_balloons.\u202egpj' the order of codepoints is '0062 0069 0072 0074 0068 0064 0061 0079 005F 0062 0061 006C 006C 006F 006F 006E 0073 002E 202E 0067 0070 006A' so the final three characters are gjp, in that order. The corresponding bytes are passed to the console which renders the text, correctly or incorrectly.
What you get from the print statement has little to do with Python's internals and everything to do with the console/terminal and how it implements bidi and font rendering.
If you want to get a visual representation of the string, i.e. reorder the string so it is in the order it appears rather than the order it is stored you need to convert from logical to visual ordering.
Using ptfribidi:

Convert from logical to visual order, forcing base string direction to LTR.
Strip out bidi formatting characters.

s = 'birthday_balloons.\u202egpj'
import pyfribidi
import regex
regex.sub(r'[\p{Cf}]', '', pyfribidi.log2vis(s, base_direction=pyfribidi.LTR))
# 'birthday_balloons.jpg'

There is no internal mechanism for doing this in Python, Python's Unicode support is minimal and relies on third party packages for a more complete solution. If the base direction is RTL instead of LTR, the visually ordered string is 'jpg.birthday_balloons'.
Using PyICU:

Initiate a BidiTransform instance
transform string, setting direction and order for source and target.
Cast UnicodeString object to a Python string and remove bidi formatting override controls.

from icu import BidiTransform, UBiDiDirection, UBiDiMirroring, UBiDiOrder
import regex

transformer = BidiTransform()
input_text = 'birthday_balloons.\u202egpj'
result = transformer.transform(
    input_text,
    UBiDiDirection.LTR, UBiDiOrder.LOGICAL,
    UBiDiDirection.LTR, UBiDiOrder.VISUAL,
    UBiDiMirroring.OFF)
regex.sub(r'[\p{Cf}]', '', str(result))
# 'birthday_balloons.jpg'

Using python-bidi 0.6.0:
python-bidi V. 0.6.0 is a complete rewrite of the module, up until V. 0.6.0, the module was a pure python impelmentation of the UBA. V. 0.6.0 implemented a python wrapper around the unicode-bidi Rust crate.
The module provides both the existing V5 API and the V6 Rust based API. For the scenario in the question they produce subtly different results. The key difference in for the question is the presence or absence of the override formatting characters in the visually ordered string.
input_text = 'birthday_balloons.\u202egpj'
# V5 API - Pure Python implementation
from bidi.algorithm import get_display as get_display5
get_display5(input_text)
# 'birthday_balloons.jpg'

# V6 API - Wrapper for unicode-bidi Rust crate.
from bidi import get_display as get_display6
import regex
get_display6(input_text)
# 'birthday_balloons.\u202ejpg'
regex.sub(r'[\p{Cf}]', '', get_display6(input_text))
# 'birthday_balloons.jpg'


Thank you for the feedback. I was looking for a more general approach that processes the string internally similar to how python does when I use print() rather than literally cleaning the string with specific functionality that can't be used on other cases.

@Ethan what other cases would need to be supported, and more importantly what is the purpose? In theory a method that would allow you to posses it as a visual sequence rather than a logical sequence would open up security holes in a code base. If RLO/LRO/PDF are in the mix I'm either working with historic writing systems, testing RTL writing systems not included in Unicode yet , or working on security functions.

@Ethan internally Python stores and processes the string in logical format. The print command doesn't do anything special with it. The string is still the same. The rendering occurs within the console/terminal, if the console has bidi support the text is rendered in visual order. Print does nothing special with the string. You'd need python bindings to external libraries such as ICU4C, Fribidi, Harfbuzz, etc. I'll see if I can add an example to my existing answer.

I really appreciate it. Still a little confused on why you have to sub out the bidi chars (RTL, LTR) as it would make sense for pyfribidi to do so when it visually interprets the string I'm assuming based on them though.

@Ethan, I found that pyfribidi or maybe its  the upstream fribidilib leaves the overrides in place. Reality is using bidi overrides is vary rare. Most devs would never deal with scenarios where overrides need to be used. More likely they will see it as an attack vector, so just need to identify or detect rather than convert.

Will see what PyICU does with it, and will test other libraries I am aware of.

@Ethan, PyICU also leaves RLO in place.

@Ethan I've updated the answer to include PyICU and python-bidi solutions.

@Ethan to answer your question about retention of RLO:  https://unicode.org/reports/tr9/#Retaining_Explicit_Formatting_Characters

The \u202e character is the right-to-left override, and its "sibling" \u202d is the left-to-right override.
To interpret those characters so that all characters are placed in the string in the same order as they would be printed, you could use this function:
def apply_direction(s):
    def recur(s, ltr):
        try:
            i = s.index("\u202d\u202e"[ltr])
        except ValueError:
            return s
        return s[:i] + recur(s[i+1:], not ltr)[::-1]
    return recur(s, True).replace("\u202d", "").replace("\u202e", "")

Used on your example:
s = "birthday_balloons.\u202egpj"
s = apply_direction(s)
print(s)  # birthday_balloons.jpg (last three characters reordered)


Thank you for the feedback. I tried to make my question a little more clear. I was looking to process it internally in a more general way so I can deal with other cases in the same way.

What other cases are you referring to?
